# Passing id from foreach loop to another page without using $_GET (id in url)

Tags: php, post, get

For now I have this code which passes variables based on an id in the URL:

```
 foreach ($allUnsteadyState as $list) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $list['project_name'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $list['project_date'] ?></td>
                        <td><a href="unsteady_state_user.php?id=<?php echo $list['id'] ?>">Go to project</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
```

And catch it on another page through an function with this code:

```
 $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
    $db = $this->dbconn;
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM unsteady_state WHERE id = :id ");
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

And so on.

For security reasons I don't want to show the id in the url, so I tried to use $_POST and $_SESSION without succes. Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: You could always look into something like encodings, such as `str_rot13` or other encoding methods, this would hide the true ID in the URL, but as far as removing it, there are not any practical ways of doing it.

Comment: Use a form with post method.

Comment: You first have to answer the question: Why is having the id in the URL a security problem? You haven't explained this, and it is at the root of the problem you're trying to solve. I wonder if that problem really exists, or if you only think it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `$_POST`. You'll need a form. You can wrap one around your table.

```
<form action="unsteady_state_user.php" method="post">
    <table>...</table>
</form>
```

Then use buttons instead of links.

```
<?php foreach ($allUnsteadyState as $list): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $list['project_name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list['project_date'] ?></td>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" name="id" value="<?php echo $list['id'] ?>">
        Go to project
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The ID won't be in the URL. You can get it from `$_POST['id']`

However, ***it will still be in the page source*** so depending on what your security concerns are this may not work for you.